# asp.net treeview nodes remaining in state

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I have an asp.net/c# treeview that is populated via a database view.  As part of the process the user clicks on the node, which brings up the node's data in a form - the user updates the from, and in so doing the row is removed from the view. Ive tested this on my development machine and that is exactly how it works.

After the form is updated I run the method to re-populate the treeview.  The problem is the row still appears, even though its not in the view.  Thinking it must be a state issue and I needed to force the treeview to re-create itself, I inserted a treeview.Nodes.Clear() above the database call, but its still showing the node.  I shut down my browser, makes no difference.  Finally I shut down my dev local server, and then finally the node doesnt appear.

The only "solution" Ive seen is to set EnableViewState = false, which makes the tree view unusable.
Does anyone know how I can refresh the treeview?
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: can you show some code? the way you query the database and the way you populate the TreeView. is this web forms?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I took the easy way out, and removed that functionality :-)